# How to rename each node(vehicle) in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

Good morning

This is my first time using OMNET++ Veins.

I have some questions. I want to name each car(node). So I modify [TraCIScenarioManager.ned](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/6b0fad86a04386f58cd5c756325b8b2ad2189b77/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.ned#L46) in line 46. But this will change the name of all vehicles at the same time. Is there any other way to name each car individually?

In addition, except through TraCIScenarioManager to join the moving nodes(cars), is there other method can manually add moving nodes(cars)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question has two parts. Focusing on the first part, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. By default, the `TraCIScenarioManager` calls the nodes it creates simply `node[0]`, `node[1]`, `node[2]` and so on. What would you like them to be called instead?

Comment: The second part of what you asked seems to be an entirely different question. You will make it much easier for other users to find this question (and the answer to it) if you create a separate question on this site.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will re-post the the second question.